# c# Comparing strings from Oracle and SQL server

Tags: sql, oracle

I think I have an encoding problem that needs to be fixed.
Is there a way to compare strings across code pages?

Oracle returns a string "TEST - My String" with the minus sign encoded as ascii 63.
SQL Server quite correctly returns the string with the minus encoded as 45.

Is there a way to compare these strings?
Does the framework contain a comparison that is capable of ignoring code page mismatches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the overloads of string.compare, probably:

```
if (string.Equals(value1, value2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
   ...
}
```

More useful info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx

Comment: Hi, I have accepted your answer. It's not strictly speaking correct, but there isn't a better one I don't think. Strings have to be compared within the code page they originate from. I have elected to solve the problem by using a fuzzy search. Alternatively one could convert the strings to the same code page but that's too much P.T.